# Gems not loading in Ruby (perhaps due to path)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

After successfully installing the tagfile gem, I try to include it using

```
require 'tagfile'
```

and see this error:

```
cannot load such file -- tagfile
```

I think that this may have to do with ruby running in a different environment than my gem command. It looks like gem uses

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
```

whereas ruby is in /bin/ruby

Comment: I think you'll find those are symlinks to each other

Comment: Neither of the files appear to be symlinks...

Answer (score 1):

My current approach for this:

```
$ which gem
/usr/bin/gem
$ less /usr/bin/gem
```

Now look at the first line. That's the ruby interpreter `gem` is using, and will install your gems in a way so that only this version of the interpreter will find them.

You can either:

1. Use the same interpreter as your `gem` command is using.
2. Try using
   the same version of `gem` as your default interpreter. Usually `gem`
   is a symbolic link to `gem1.9.3`, `gem2.0`, `gem2.1` etc so you can
   substitute one of those commands with the version suffixed instead.